# Quick regexp to introduce C# 6's nameof(x) instead of string literals in my code

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015

So in my code I have a lot of places where I'm using `_SendPropertyChanged("FancyFuuBar");` which I'd like to replace with `_SendPropertyChanged(nameof(FancyFuuBar));` - obviously the `FancyFuuBar` part is not the same everywhere but I'd like a single command that can tackle this everywhere.

I "know" this is possible with regex (actually, I think and assume it is, but I know not).

How do I have regex "remember" the `FancyFuuBar` name and use it again in the replace instance? Is this possible in Visual Studio 2015 find and replace?

If this is not possible with a single regex, what's the best way to go about doing it, without loosing control? I.e. I would like to be able to limit this to a few files at first and preferably be able to click "Find Next" and then decide if I want to Replace that instance or not.

I dare not big bang this on all the code just yet.

Comment: That's not nearly dumb enough for me to understand. Doesn't that just match everything in my code? How would that not replace all the things? Wat.

Comment: the green part is the matched one..it is captured and accessed by `$1`..what do you want to replace it with

Comment: I don't want to mach ``_DoSomethingElse("FancyFuuBar");`` for example

Comment: I don't want to replace ``FancyFuuBar`` with anything, that part should remain. I thought that was clear from the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask for is [*backreferences*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) that hold the value captured with corresponding [*capturing groups*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

It is easy if you do not have any complex cases with lazy matching:

```
\b_SendPropertyChanged\("(.*?)"\);
```

And replace with `_SendPropertyChanged(nameof($1));`

[image]

```
                                           V
```

[image]

Here is the structure of a match with the current expression:

```
\b_SendPropertyChanged\("(.*?)"\);
|                        ^$1-^   |
^--------------- Match Value ----^
```

What we match will get replaced with the replacement pattern. The captures start with 0 index, and the zeroth group is the whole match. `$1` is the value captured with the first `(...)`. And so on.

Comment: I added the links to the regular-expressions.info to read more about capturing groups, what they are, and backreferences.

Comment: What I don't really understand is why ``_SendPropertyChanged("`` isn't a part of $1, since that's what is being matched? But I'm not gonna lie, the less I read about regular expressions, the happier I am as a person. They're like that weird powertool you have to call your dad every time you want to use. I'm sure I *could* learn to use them properly, but it's just too dangerous for what it's worth.

Comment: I will add a "graph"

Comment: No, please, you don't have to do that! Hahah what I want has been accomplished, thank you so much for your time!